# Open Office XML Parsing Error

Tags: xml, xsd, openxml, xml-validation

I am attempting to create a pptx file programmatically. However, when I try to open my pptx file, I receive very generic errors from LibreOffice and also from Microsoft PowerPoint. How can I go about getting more specific error information so I can find out what I am doing wrong in the underlying XML?

I am using PHP to create these files, not anything on the Microsoft stack by the way.

Comment: You can download the [OpenXML Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) and choose the Validate option. That should list any errors in the XML.

Comment: @petelids Unfortunately I am on an Ubuntu machine. It seems like installing the SDK requires a Windows machine. If that is truly the only solution, then I can get my hands on a Windows machine I suppose, but a solution that would run on my development machine would be definitely be preferred.

Comment: Ah, that won't help then :). Can you use the OpenXML SDK on Mono and use the [OpenXmlValidator class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497334(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: @petelids Oh interesting. I'll try it out, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @petelids Hey, so I actually got my hands on a windows machine and the XML validator is doing exactly what I want. If you post an answer I will accept it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks @thatidiotguy - I'm glad I could help you out and I appreciate you coming back to me. I've posted an answer, if it needs more info please feel free to edit or let me know and I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenXML Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) has a Validate action on it which will list any errors you may have. You can choose whether to validate against the 2007, 2010 or 2013 formats.

The following is an example where I've added an extra cell element outside of a row:

[image]

The tool also has a useful feature to allow you to generate code from an existing document. This can be extremely handy if you're stuck on how to generate a particular feature.

Comment: Hey, quick question. How is it possible that I run my pptx file through the XML validator and get no errors, but when I go to open the file in Powerpoint I am still informeld that there are problems that it needs to repair?

Comment: A few things it's worth checking @thatidiotguy - 1) are you using the correct version on the validator? 2) do you have the order of the elements correct? I have a nagging feeling I recall this problem and it turned out to be an element ordering issue. 3) It might be that I'm misremembering 2) and maybe it's a missing element that's actually required by Powerpoint but not by the validator?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will look into those possibilities. Is there any good way to compare the XML of the pptx file I generated with the "repaired" one's XML that PowerPoint creates?

Comment: Oh nevermind, the productivity tool actually has a comparison tool. Nifty!

Comment: I'd forgotten about the comparison in the productivity tool. If you don't mind letting me know I'd be keen to know what was causing the repair message...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest. I did a comparison and made some changes, but I am not totally clear which one of the changes fixed it. The changes involved putting some default style information in presentation.xml, removing a content type declaration for custom.xml when I did not have a file called custom.xml (if I had to guess that would be the problem),  and removing the val attribute on a16:rowId elements. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Download the OOXML PresentationML XSD, pml.xsd, from the [Standard ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).  You can find it in the zip at the link marked, [ECMA-376 4th edition Part 1](http://ECMA-376%204th%20edition%20Part%201) in the `OfficeOpenXML-XMLSchema-Strict.zip` file.  (There are also RELAX NG schemas available as well.)

Using Xerces or any other standard, validating XML parser should provide you with good diagnostic messages when the OOXML you generate is invalid.

Comment: This will tell me that if individual files have issues, but what if the issue is the relationships defined between the XML files? Such as problems with my XML files in the `_rels` folders? Or what if I am missing a file that LibreOffice is expecting? Still this could definitely be useful to make sure that I don't have any syntax errors.

Comment: Converting to flat OPC and using a FOPC XSD would help, but unfortunately last I looked they'd not defined XML schema of any type for FOPC.  I believe that validating the main XML, although not complete as you say, will often be very helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Do you know of any tools on Linux that you are aware of that will actually do the validation process? Ideally, I could point it to the unzipped pptx directory and it would go through and do its thing recursively.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of any other tools that can perform the more comprehensive, cross-file validation process that you describe.

Comment: Ok well thank you very much for your suggestions. I will definitely give it a shot if a more comprehensive solution is not provided.